# How to properly mix sequential steps within parallel execution in an Airflow DAG?

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow DAG I am writing where step_1 and step_2 run sequentially, and then in parallel kicked off three additional steps: X, Y, Z. Once those three steps completed, they run a final step, step_3. My DAG was written as:

`step_1 >> step_2 >> [X, Y, Z] >> step_3`

This worked just fine. However, I realized that X actually has two dependencies, we'll call them A and B, that need to run first. What I wanted to do was have those three - A, B, and X - run sequentially within one parallel lane, alongside Y and Z.

I wrote the DAG wiring as:

`step_1 >> step_2 >> [A >> B >> X, Y, Z] >> step_3`

This does not seem to have the expected results. I wanted A to be kicked off after step_2 ran, but it appears step_2 is still wired directly to X, with A and B just kind of... unlinked to either step_1 or step_2.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I know that I could pull A and B out of parallelism:

`step_1 >> step_2 >> A >> B >> [X, Y, Z] >> step_3`

But if possible I'd like to figure out a better approach. I have also read about subDAGs, but those seem overwrought for the simple tasks these steps are running.

Comment: It would be easier to assist if you can add image of how you want the dependencies to be. It's very hard to understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the proper way to write the wiring:

```
step_1 >> step_2 >> [A, Y, Z] 

A >> B >> X >> step_3
Y >> step_3
Z >> step_3
```

You transition from `step_2` into the parallel operator, listing the first action that must be taken along each parallel path (in two of the three cases, they're the only action). Then you list each of those first actions, and write up the wiring for each path, with each path ending with the step on which they join.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: does something ilke `[X, Y, Z] >> step_3` work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your requested dependencies.
You mentioned that:

```
step_1 >> step_2 >> [A, Y, Z] 
A >> B >> X >> step_3
Y >> step_3
Z >> step_3
```

Gives you what you want which is:
[image]

But you also mentioned that you want A,B to be executed in parallel.
This can be done by using:

```
chain(step_1, step_2, [A, B])
[A, B] >> X >> step_3
step_2 >> [Y, Z] >> step_3
```

Example:

[image]

Full code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain

with DAG(
    "stackoverflow_question",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 6, 7),
    schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:

    step_1 = DummyOperator(task_id='step_1')
    step_2 = DummyOperator(task_id='step_2')
    step_3 = DummyOperator(task_id='step_3')

    A = DummyOperator(task_id='A')
    B = DummyOperator(task_id='B')
    X = DummyOperator(task_id='X')
    Y = DummyOperator(task_id='Y')
    Z = DummyOperator(task_id='Z')

    chain(step_1, step_2, [A, B])
    [A, B] >> X >> step_3
    step_2 >> [Y, Z] >> step_3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pools to have operators work in a sequential or parallel way, sequential pool having only 1 slot available.

```
airflow pools set "sequential" 1 "pool for non-parallelizable operations" 
airflow pools set "parallel" 4 "pool for parallelizable operations"
```

Then assign sequential or parallel pool to each operator accordingly.